# how to open a webpage, fill an html form, submit it, get the form's result and then post the information to another activity in android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, .net

We have an `aspx` page with a form in it and we can only process this form in a browser-based environment (ie we cannot create a web service for it.

What we want to do is that we want to process this information in an android application. We want to send some initial data to this page, let the user fill it, submit the form, and then return the results to the calling activity, so we can show a proper message and act accordingly.

let me give an example for this usecase:

We are in `activity A` and in this activity we have a button that triggers the start of our journey:

```
//we are in activity A
mOurButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("additional_data_we_need", adittionalData);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});
```

Now we are in `activity B` and here, we should comunicate with that webpage that I was talking about, passing it the `additionalData` that is in this activity's extra bundle (it is acceptable if we do it using query strings or any other way).

After the user fills the form, and hit submit,we do some operation on it and return some results to another (web)page or in the current (web)page's postback (again it is acceptable if we use query strings, post method or any other way; whicever way that works for this senario). We get this returned result in android side and then get the result to `ActivityA` :

```
//we are in acitivity B
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int adittionalData = getIntent().getExtras().getIntExtra("adittional_data_we_nedd");
    //this is the first place that I don't know what to do
    callTheWebPageAndGiveItTheData(adittionalData);
}

public void SomeListenerOfTheReturnedDataFromTheWebpage(Bundle returnedData //doesn't necessarily need to be of bundle type) {
    intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("return_bundle", returnedData);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

What can I do to achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance for your kind answers

Comment: You can read every day on this site how to post some values to a webserver and read the returned result page. Pretty basic. You do not need a browser or webview for it. You will not open the webpage.

Comment: as I said, we cannot use any other resource than this web page. We have already done all the other parts with restful web services to communicate with the server. But for this particular part, we have no other options (we want to communicate with a service that we don't provide, and that service is only available the way I described. so no other option is possible)

Comment: You talk nonsense. Of course you can post data to that service the same way a browser would do it with that page.

Comment: You obviously are not living a third world country. In here this particular service is only being served by the government itself and the only way they are letting others use it is to redirect the user to a gate (which is a webpage), they collect the user's data and then give the result back to a url you specified for them with query strings. We don't have any control over this process

Comment: I wonder why you think you need to control that process. Take that process for granted. If you would otherwise load that page in a browser, and fill in a form and click a submit button then that all you can do just posting that data to the server. If you think its not possible then please make clear why not.

Comment: I was giving an example with the mentioned form. The actual form that I am talking about is not on our servers. as I said, we should redirect the user to a page, and the user HIMSELF should fill that form, (we cannot collect user's data ourselves at this stage.Since it is considered a fraud if we do so), the form will be submitted (again, not by us), and after that, the server (not ours) processes the data, and redirects the user to a page we have set for them with the results (such as if the process was successful or not and etc)